# Is it "What the Government should do" or "What should the Government do"?

Tags: word-order, question-marks

Is it "What the Government should do" or "What should the Government do"?

If you want context, I am using this sentence as **a title for a slide in a presentation**. Should I even use a question mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to say.

**What the Government should do** is a statement. It indicates that what is on the slide is a true fact: Here are some actions, and the Government *should* take them. Done. You are asserting that you know the correct answer to the problem.

**What should the Government do?** is a rhetorical question (note that you must include the question mark). You pose the query and then attempt to answer it with the content of the slide. This is less presumptuous; you are providing *your opinion* about the situation and *proposing* rather than decreeing a solution.

In reality you can use either one without worrying too much. If the presentation is for a project in a class I might use the question, and if it is for a paid consultation I would perhaps use the statement—it carries more weight. But really the difference will be minimal.

Comment: To my mind, *What the Government should do* is a ***noun phrase*** (not a complete sentence / statement). Compare *I know **Mr Smith**, I know **the answer**, I know **what to do***. Offhand I can't think of any context where using the "wrong" one of OP's two suggestions would be acceptable to native Anglophones. Apart from as a "heading / title", where normal grammar / syntax doesn't apply anyway.